# Macro To Format Cell Width

Tags: vba, excel, macros, excel-2013

I used macro recorder to record this macro that I need to format some columns as $ and auto-fit the columns.  However, when I try to execute this macro from the VBE no formatting changes take place.  What should be altered in this syntax to properly format my data?

```
Public Function Format()

Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

With ws
    Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Columns("D:M").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "$#,##0"
    Range("A1").Select
End With

Next

End Function
```

Comment: When using the With block you need to add a `.` to the front of every object that is a child of that worksheet.  So the first line would be `.Cells.Select`

Comment: @ScottCraner - this gives me an error of "Method or data member not found" on this line .Selection.NumberFormat = "$#,##0"

Comment: `Selection` is not a child of the worksheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with Scott Craner's comment you need to include the preceeding .   however you can shorten this bit of code by removing the with block and use the worksheet qualifier

```
Public Sub Format()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Cells.Columns("D:M").NumberFormat = "$#,##0"
        ws.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        ws.Activate
        ws.Range("A1").Select
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm glad you switched the order of the `NumberFormat` and the `AutoFit` - that was annoying me in the original question!